# External Resource links used multiple times on a web page ,does it cause round trips?

Tags: javascript, css, networking, browser

When a browser encounters a reference to a external javascript on a "single" html page multiple times then would it reload the .js file multiple time/cause a round trip to the server or does the browser automatically detect that the previous url was downloaded and not make a request again to the server?.

Would this be irrespective of the Cache header of the file?

What is the behaviour by default across all the spectrum of web browsers, and how does it apply for external css links?

Comment: Yes and No. Yes, the browser will cache resources and not reload unless resource is not modified on the server. So round trip is made but may not reload the resource. No, because it also depends on the header (Cache-Control:max-age).